# Type constraints become huge and unreadable for simple code

Tags: haskell, design-patterns, data-structures, typeclass

Mind the following code:

```
-- A n-dimensional axis aligned bounding box.
data AABB v a = AABB {
    aabbMin :: !(v a), 
    aabbMax :: !(v a)
    } deriving (Show)

-- `v` is a container, representing the number of dimensions. Ex:
-- type Box2DFloat = AABB V2 Float
-- type Box4DFloat = AABB V4 Float 

-- A n-dimensional ray.
data Ray v a = Ray {
    rayPos :: !(v a),
    rayDir :: !(v a)
    } deriving (Show)

-- Traces a n-d ray through a n-d box, returns 
-- the intersection indexes (tmin, tmax).
intersectAABB 
    :: (Foldable f, 
        Metric f, 
        Ord a, 
        Num (f a), 
        Fractional (f a), 
        Floating a) 
    => Ray f a 
    -> AABB f a 
    -> [a]
intersectAABB (Ray rayPos rayDir) (AABB aabbMin aabbMax) 
    = [tmin, tmax] where
        t1   = (aabbMin - rayPos) / rayDir
        t2   = (aabbMax - rayPos) / rayDir
        tmin = foldr1 max $ liftI2 min t1 t2
        tmax = foldr1 min $ liftI2 max t1 t2
```

That is an usual Ray→AABB intersection function, and it is pretty simple and clean, except for **the type signature, which is almost bigger than the function itself**! Someone suggested I could use kind constraints that "encapsule my needs" to make it less verbose, but I can't find a kind constraint that "encapsules my needs" properly. "My needs", on this case, are basically "the type acts like a number should". So, on my mind, the following would make sense:

```
class Real a where
    ... anything I want a real number to do ...

instance Real Float where
    ...

instance (Real a) => Real (V2 a) where
    ...

instance (Real a) => Real (V3 a) where
    ...

type AABB a = V2 a
type Ray a  = V2 a

type Box2DFloat = AABB (V2 Float)
type Box4DFloat = AABB (V4 Float)
type Ray2D a = Ray (V2 a)
type Ray3DRatio = Ray (V3 Ratio)
... etc ...
```

That way, my signatures would become, simply:

```
intersectAABB :: (Real r, Real s) => Ray r -> AABB r -> [s]
```

Which looks much better. But, if nobody using Haskell has bothered to define such class, there should be a reason. What is the reason there is no "Real" class, and, if defining such a class would be a bad idea, what is the proper solution to my issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your particular example could be solved by using `^-^` and `liftI2 (/)` instead of `-` and `/` respectively. This reduces the constraint to `(Foldable f, Metric f, Ord a, Floating a)`.

Using `ConstraintKinds` you can make constant aliases to reduce cluster:

```
type OrderedField a = (Ord a, Floating a)
type FoldableMetric f = (Foldable f, Metric f)
```

So the constraint becomes `(FoldableMetric f, OrderedField a)`. You can also do this without `ConstraintKinds` by making a dummy class:

```
class (Ord a, Floating a) => OrderedField a
instance (Ord a, Floating a) => OrderedField a
```

but this needs `UndecidableInstances`.

Vectors aren't really numbers. You can't write reasonable `Ord` or `Real` instances for them (whether they should even have a `Num` instance is debatable). I think keeping the vector and number types separate is a good thing.

Comment: When exactly Vectors don't act like numbers?

Comment: How would you do `toRational :: Real a => a -> Rational` for a vector? You can do some operations component wise but they don't always make sense in the geometric interpretation of a vector, like multiplying. Normally when you "multiply" two vectors is a dot product or cross product.

Comment: Not convinced, I'd need more elaboration than that, but that's out of the scope of the question, of course. Thank you!

Comment: Note: moved this question to [math SO](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1286711/vectors-arent-really-numbers-how-sound-is-that-statement), just in case...

Comment: @Viclib What about complex numbers? (there's no `Metric` instance for `Complex` for some reason, but you could write your function in terms of `Additive`). With your current definition this makes no sense but it would work if you did component-wise division using `liftI2 (/)`. I recommend you stick to the standard "vector" notation (`^+^` ect.), they're there for a reason and you'll have nicer type signatures (`Num (f a)` is ugly).

Comment: @Viclib, one simple way vectors are not numbers is in the type of "multiplication".  Vectors have scaling (scalar * vector -> vector) and inner product (vector * vector -> scalar), but no multiplication (vector * vector -> vector)

Answer (score 6):

Use constraint synonyms:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ConstraintKinds #-}

type ConstraintSynonym f a = (
  Foldable f,
  Metric f,
  Ord a, 
  Num (f a), 
  Fractional (f a), 
  Floating a)
```

With `ConstraintKinds`, lifted tuples can be used to express conjunction of constraints (and `()` can refer to the trivially satisfied constraint). You can now use `ConstraintSynonym` instead of the big tuple of constraints in annotations.

Comment: Thanks, can I ask just a small clarification? There are some functions that use different constraints across that library, but all somewhat similar. So, you suggest I should use a single synonym that covered everything, or one per function, covering the exact function needs? How would it be called idiomatically?

Comment: I think synonyms should be defined in a way so that they can be used as much as possible. Single use synonyms are no good. If have multiple slightly different synonyms, you could try finding some unifying pattern or principle and use type families to generate the constraints (type families can also return `Constraint`-s).